# Is there any trade off for marking and event Async in VB

Tags: vb.net, asynchronous, async-await, task, task-parallel-library

I am working on a legacy code base and I have modified few of the database calls to be async functions.

So my DbMethod is now :

```
Private Async Function ExecuteDbOperation(ByVal ReturnMessage As String) As Task(Of Integer)

   data = Await exec.ExecuteReaderAsync()

End Function
```

I am calling this method on button click ,So I have two solutions,

```
Protected Sub btnDecantBarCodeSubmit_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

 var res = ExecuteDbOperation("").Result

 End Sub


 Protected Async Sub btnDecantBarCodeSubmit_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

 var res = Await ExecuteDbOperation("")

 End Sub
```

Now is there a trade of if I make event handler as Async or I should just opt in for .result.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean with "trade off". It depends on what's more suitable in your "context". If you use Async/Await, your UI will be responsive, accepting user input. If that's ok, go for it. The other method will block the UI until `ExecuteReaderAsync()` returns. If that's ok, maybe because it prevents further checking on user interaction with the UI, go for it. As a note, as it is I think the `ExecuteDbOperation("").Result` will block forever, because there's no context to mashal the continuation back. You'ld need `data = Await exec.ExecuteReaderAsync().ConfigureAwait(False)`

Answer (score 2):

`.Result` is a blocking call and will **deadlock** an application that has a `SynchronizationContext` like yours, assuming your using WPF, WinForms, etc. If you have `async` work to do then it is recommended to mark your event handler, *and only an event handler*, `Async Sub`. Every other method should be marked as `Async Function ... As Task` or `Async Function ... As Task(Of T)`.  For more details see [Don't Block on Async Code](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html)

```
 Protected Async Sub btnDecantBarCodeSubmit_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
     'Await captures the current Syncronization Context here
     var res = Await ExecuteDbOperation("")
     'And Restores it here
     '...Update UI...'
 End Sub
```